# Error while executing a program for calculator and c++ forbids comparison

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int a,b,c;
    cin>>a>>b>>c;
    if(c=="+"){
      cout<<a+b<<endl;
    }
    else if(c=="-"){
      cout<<a-b<<endl;
    }
    else if(c=="*"){
      cout<<a*b<<endl;
    }
    else if(c=="/"){
      cout<<a/b<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting the above error as I executed the program. I wanted to make a program for the calculator.

Comment: You should post the error message. Anyway, `c` is declared as `int` but you try to used it a a string.

Answer (score 0):

like said above, you declare `c` as an `int`, but you want a `char` (character).
In addition, you should use `' '` instead of `" "` for comparaing `char` (like said in comments, `"` is for strings).

The (ugly) code below works as expected :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int a,b;
    char c;

    cin>>a>>b>>c;

    if(c=='+'){
      cout<<a+b<<endl;
    }
    else if(c=='-'){
      cout<<a-b<<endl;
    }
    else if(c=='*'){
      cout<<a*b<<endl;
    }
    else if(c=='/'){
      cout<<a/b<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```